# US international layout does not appear in Gnome

Tags: 16.04, keyboard-layout, ubuntu-gnome

The list of all keyboard layouts proposed by Gnome (I run Ubuntu Gnome 16.04) does not include the quite standard US international (any variant of it). There are numerous layouts for many country, but not this one.

**Question.** How can I fix that?

Session-wide, a `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-layout` does what I want, but this is only session-wide.

**Additional question.** It seems that the keyboard layout can be changed at several level (Xorg, Gnome, and a more fundamental level on which keyboard-configuration acts).  I've been unable to find doc on the topic, could anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 6):

Editing the setting manually in *dconf* do the trick.
Namely, execute `dconf-editor`, find `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources.sources` ant put the value `[('xkb', 'us+intl')]`.

*[Oddly enough, the box `show-all-sources` was unchecked, so I checked it but that changes nothing to the problem of the international variant not being displayed in the layout list.]*

Comment: Wow, I couldn't find that at all through the GUI, but that did the trick!